Projection matrices and generalized inverses
I am trying to characterise the projection matrices using the singular value decomposition (SVD) in order to better understand oblique projections.
Orthogonal projection
A projection matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is a matrix such that $P^2 = P$. If $P$ is symmetric then it is the orthogonal projection on $span (P)$. For a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, the orthogonal projection on its range can be written as $P = AA^{+}$ where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. If I have the singular value decomposition of $A$, then I can build the pseudoinverse as:
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} U_{img} & U_{ker} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}V_{img}^T \\ V_{ker}^T\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
A^{+} = \begin{bmatrix} V_{img} & V_{ker} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma^{-1}_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}U_{img}^T \\ U_{ker}^T\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Then $P$ takes the following form:
\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix} U_{img} & U_{ker} \end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} U_{img}^T \\ U_{ker}^T\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The above shows that we have a projection on $span(U_{img})$ along $span(U_{ker})$, i.e., the orthogonal projection. Equivalently I could have written $P = A(A^TA)^{+}A^T$. For oblique projections the latter takes the form $P = A(B^TA)^{+}B^T$ instead, where $span(A)$ is the space on which I want to project, and $span(B)$ is the orthogonal complement of the space along which I want to project.
Other generalized inverses
My question is whether there is a nice way to characterize all possible projection matrices in terms of generalized inverses. That is, taking a matrix $A$, its inner or $1$-inverses $A^{(1)}$ satisfy $AA^{(1)}A = A$ and thus $(AA^{(1)})^2 = (AA^{(1)}A)A^{(1)} = AA^{(1)}$, meaning that is  a projection matrix. Similarly if $A^{(2)}$ is a $2$-inverse, then $A^{(2)}AA^{(2)} = A^{(2)}$ and $(AA^{(2)})^2 = A(A^{(2)}AA^{(2)}) = AA^{(2)}$, meaning that it is also a projection.
Are there any other projection matrices that are not covered by the above cases?
Now considering the $1$-inverse case, I can study it in terms of the SVD since any $1$-inverse has the form:
\begin{equation}
A^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} V_{img} & V_{ker} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma^{-1}_{11} & X \\ Y & Z \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}U_{img}^T \\ U_{ker}^T\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
for any matrices $X,Y,Z$. Then the expression $AA^{(1)}$ takes the form:
\begin{equation}
AA^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} U_{img} & U_{ker} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I & \Sigma_{11}X \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} U_{img}^T \\ U_{ker}^T \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
It is clear that this is a projection on $span(U_{img}) = span(A)$. It can be written as $U_{img}U_{img}^T + U_{img}\Sigma_{11}XU_{ker}^T$ where the first part is the orthogonal projection $AA^{+}$ and the second part is as far as I can tell what changes it to an oblique projection. My understanding is then that the space along which I project is
\begin{equation}
\{y \in \mathbb{R}^m \,:\, (U_{img}+U_{ker}(X\Sigma_{11})^T)^T y = 0\}
\end{equation}
I am not aware of an SVD characterization of $2$-inverses (I know that for $(1,2)$-inverses it suffices that $Z = Y\Sigma_{11}X$).
Is there any way I can study the above in terms of $2$-inverses in a similar manner, or does the $1$-inverse case already cover all possible oblique projections on $span(A)$?
